# Show keyboard in alertdialog when lock screen it's active

Tags: android

I made an application fullscreen and kiosk mode, this app shows the screen in front of lock screen using the flags, but when I open a Dialog and try to write with the keyboard in EditText field the keyboard not appears.

If I close the dialog the keyboard appears, this only happened with the lock screen, after unlocking the phone and repeat the process the keyboard appears in the dialog

I tried to use the InputManager to force the keyboard appears and the flags to maintain visibly the keyboard but not works

Here it's the code of my Dialog class and put a toast to see when i do the focus, the toast only appears when the phone it's unlocked.

```java
yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_main);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        password.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Focus",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I also got same issue in 1 project, I didn't find solution for this so far..